# Returning gracefully from Matlab back to python

Tags: python

I call Matlab code from python as

```
matlab_cmd_string = MatlabExePth+ " -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r "
fname = 'CompareMse '
mat_cmd = matlab_cmd_string +  fname  + ", exit\""
```

which gets translated as

> 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop
>   -wait -logfile FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r CompareMse , exit'

The Matlab code does its job and then prints error and stops execution using following construct:

```
if(mse> thr)
    error('mse has increased');
end
```

However, the control is not given back to python.

I tried following commands in python:

```
msg=subprocess.check_output(mat_cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
```

msg comes empty and console window dosn't show up anything as control is not got back. Same with following method :

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(mat_cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
output = out.upper()
proc.returncode
```

If I write following in matlab,

```
if(mse> thr)
    warning('mse has increased');
    return
end
```

I get control back to python with following:

```
 msg=subprocess.check_output(mat_cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
 proc = subprocess.Popen(mat_cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  out, err = proc.communicate()
    output = out.upper()
    proc.returncode
```

**msg,out**  show as **""**  , **err** is  **NONE** , and    **proc.returncode**  is   **0**

What is need is functionality in Matlab:

```
for i=1:3
 % Some code here
 if(mse> thr)
       [print error,return user defined exit code and error message back to python variable]
 if (mse_new >mse_old)
       [print warning,do not return, but capture warning back to
        Python variable]
 % some code here
```

the difficulty with  **warning** is that if the condition for  **warning** happens in loop iteration 1, and not for 2nd and third time, Python should be able to understand that Matlab code had not errors but one warning and should capture that.( and matlab should not exit at iteration 1 of for loop but complete all iterations)

any ideas ?
sedy

Comment: How are you calling Matlab? Once its execution is stopped, the flow should go back to the parent (Python).

Comment: @Eugene  please see my first quote which shows the command..

Comment: That's not the code. What is the line in Python?

Comment: Have you tried to use `subprocess.check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs) ` ?

Comment: @RobinCurbelo Robin, I can't get it working with your suggestion too

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `subprocess.check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)`. You can capture the output of any given command. Check the Python 2.7 subprocess doc in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
msg = subprocess.check_output([MatlabExePth, "-nosplash", "-wait", "-logfile", "FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log", "-minimize", "-r", fname, ", exit"])
print msg
```