# How to return values from Matlab to Python when executing a Matlab routine via subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, matlab

I can call and pass parameters to Matlab using Python like so:

```
    MatlabExePth=checkMatlabExe()
    matlab_cmd_string = MatlabExePth+ " -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -r "
    changeDirectory("C:\\SVN\\Matlabcode")
    mat_cmd = matlab_cmd_string + "\"" + 'testMatlabReturnToPython' +  ", exit\""
    # test return value Method 1
    msg=subprocess.check_output(mat_cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
    # test return value method 2
     proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
     out, err = proc.communicate()
```

where testMatlabReturnToPython.m code looks like:

```
    function [err,err_cod] = testMatlabReturnToPython()
      try

        mse=0.01;
        thr=0.1;
        if(mse>thr)
            err = 'no error'
            err_cod = 0;
        else
            % cause an exception
            [1 2]*[1 2];
        end
     catch
         err = ' error'
         err_cod = -1;
     end
```

As with Python code, I need a way to get back the **err** and **err_code** variables back into Python (these could be arrays, cell var etc), but I haven't found a way to do so.

Note: After Calling Matlab support, found out that `import matlab.engine` will do the above but is available from matlab *R2014b*, while i have *R2013b*.

Comment: I think you have to further explain what you are doing? Calling Matlab via command line? Or via some other API?

Comment: @Daniel calling Matlab from Python. Its related to : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598006/returning-gracefully-from-matlab-back-to-python)[link]

Comment: A specific reason you use command line and not Matlab automation you can access via win32com.client in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883189/calling-matlab-functions-from-python some details about the possibilities

Comment: @Daniel Thanks Daniel, that was an excellent resource.

Answer (score 1):

How about that small following example with `try-catch`?

```
function [my_out, status] = myfun(my_inputs)
  try
    do_your_work_here;
    my_out = your_result;
    status = 1;
  catch ME
    my_out = [];
    status = -1;
    warning(ME.getReport());
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE: Regarding to your updated question, to get values from matlab function in python, you may need something similar to this in python:

```
import matlab.engine as ME
PE = ME.start_matlab()
err,err_cod = PE.testMatlabReturnToPython(nargout=2)
```

sorry that i don't have python now so cannot confirm if it runs perfectly.

Comment: seems you want to call matlab function from python? or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: yes I am able to call and pass arguments but not able to  read values back

Comment: updated the answer, you may refer to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.matlabengine-class.html for more information

Comment: then you should update that information, mention clearly which license you don't have, in your question's title, hope others can help